# Android swipe tabs that are not actionbar tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

Hey i am working on an android app and I would like to know if its possible to have swiping on tabs that are not action bar tabs just normal fragment tabs. I have been looking for this solution on the internet so if anyone knows how its done or have a link to a tutorial on how I can achieve this I will be very grateful
Thanks in advance

Comment: What are "normal fragment tabs"?

Comment: @CommonsWare They are not in the action bar They require a fragmentTabhost in their layout and they do not swipe to the left or right. That's how I would put it

Answer (score 0):

Well, the typical way of implementing swipe tabs today involves a `ViewPager` for the tab content, and some sort of tabbed indicator, such as `PagerTabStrip` or the `TabPageIndicator` from the ViewPagerIndicator library.

If you want to use `FragmentTabHost`, you can wrap the `TabWidget` in a `HorizontalScrollView` to get a swiping effect.

Answer (score 0):

In my oppinion using action bar tabs that has synced switch events with a ViewPager would be better. You can use TabHost for tab bar without action bar but in case you would like to check out, i'll drop this simple and effective tutorial here :

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, you don't use action bar, you have to use this format.
You create three tab textviews above view pager, and use this textviews for tab, now no need action bar tabs,

```
TabPagerAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(TabPagerAdapter);
        txt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#01579B"));
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Page Position
                int pagePosition=   viewPager.getCurrentItem();
                //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+pagePosition,1000).show();
                if(pagePosition==0){
                    txt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#01579B"));
                    txt2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e64b17"));
                    txt3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e64b17"));
                }
                if(pagePosition==1){
                    WL2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#01579B"));
                    WL1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e64b17"));
                    WL3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e64b17"));
                }
                if(pagePosition==2){
                    txt2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e64b17"));
                    txt3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#01579B"));
                    txt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e64b17"));
                }



            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```